# Bash: trim a parameter from both ends

Tags: bash, parameters, expansion

Greetings!

This are well know Bash parameter expansion patterns:

**${parameter#word}**, **${parameter##word}**

and

**${parameter%word}**, **${parameter%%word}**

I need to chop one part from the beginning and anoter part from the trailing of the parameter. Could you advice something for me please?

Comment: you would get a lot better answers if you provide sample input and desired output

Comment: I have a path "/.../ABC/abc.txt" and I want to get name of the host folder for file "abc.txt", which in this example is "ABC".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash version >= 3.2, you can use regular expression matching with a capture group to retrieve the value in one command:

```
$ path='/xxx/yyy/zzz/ABC/abc.txt'
$ [[ $path =~ ^.*/([^/]*)/.*$ ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
ABC
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
$ path='/xxx/yyy/zzz/ABC/abc.txt'
$ path=$(echo "$path" | sed 's|^.*/\([^/]*\)/.*$|\1|p')
$ echo $path
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's an easy way to do this without resorting to sub-shells, something you probably want to avoid for efficiency. I would just use:

```
> xx=hello_there
> yy=${xx#he}
> zz=${yy%re}
> echo ${zz}
llo_the
```

If you're not fussed about efficiency and just want a one-liner:

```
> zz=$(echo ${xx%re} | sed 's/^he//')
> echo ${zz}
llo_the
```

Keep in mind that this second method starts sub-shells - it's not something I'd be doing a lot of if your script has to run fast.

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently usit the variation of your first method:

DIRNAME="./ABC/abc.txt" DIRNAME=${DIRNAME#./} DIRNAME=${DIRNAME%/*.txt} But I don't understand why this method involves sub-shells...

Comment: The first method doesn't involve sub-shells, it's only the second that does that. I'll clarify.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to incorporate two lines of your first method to a one line?

Comment: Yes: `yy=${xx#he} ; zz=${yy%re}` :-) If you mean a single _command_, no, I don't believe so but someone with more `bash` knowledge than me may come along later.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses what Andrey asked for and it does not employ any external tool. Strategy: Use the % parameter expansion to remove the file name, then use the ## to remove all but the last directory:

```
$ path=/path/to/my/last_dir/filename.txt

$ dir=${path%/*}     

$ echo $dir
/path/to/my/last_dir

$ dir=${dir##*/}

$ echo $dir
last_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend going with bash arrays as their performance is just over 3x faster than regular expression matching.

```
$ path='/xxx/yyy/zzz/ABC/abc.txt'
$ IFS='/' arr=( $path )
$ echo ${arr[${#arr[@]}-2]}
ABC
```

This works by telling bash that each element of the array is separated by a forward slash `/` via `IFS='/'`. We access the penultimate element of the array by first determining how many elements are in the array via `${#arr[@]}` then subtracting 2 and using that as the index to the array.